# How to find words with special characters in a string sentence

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I was wondering how you can find words with special characters in a sentence, in all generality.

For example if we have the following sentence

```
I love (#coo$kies) the following cookies: $cookie[1], $cookie[2, @cookie, @cookie%, hot@dog
```

Put aside the fact that this is not how variables should be used in a string. What is the regex to retrieve '#coo$kies' `$cookie[1]`, `$cookie[2`, `@cookie`, `@cookie%`, `hot@dog` and not `I`, `love` ... `cookies` (or `cookies:`).

I used the following regex:

```
'#(\S+(?!\w+))#'
```

but the negation doesn't work, and I get every word back ("I", "love"..."cookies:").

Comment: Why use `#` if you have `$`? Try `\B\$\S*` or a more specific `\B\$\w+\[\d*]`

Comment: that # is used in php as a pattern indicator. Also I forgot to add other cases

Comment: Well, the question formatting baffled me a bit. Maybe you need [`\S*[^\w\s:;.,?!][^\s\p{P}]*`](https://regex101.com/r/uM2rK9/2)?

Comment: try this:  https://regex101.com/r/uM2rK9/3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

`(?:^| )+((\w*?[^ :,\w]+?\w*?)*)(?: |,|: |$)`

You may try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/sN7bT6/1)

Comment: It seems to pick up things like "Edward's "as well though

Comment: @LongLe Of course. Because apostrophe seems  like a special char to me. However, you can add this symbol to this group `[^ :,\w]`. It should help.

Comment: Thanks. Although it seems to be a bit brute, it certainly works well.

Comment: @LongLe Yes, there are some flaws in my regex but it would be much more complex if I try to fix them. Simplier is better :)

Answer (score 1):

No way to fetch `$cookie[2]` as it does not present in the source string.

For the rest you need to separate word delimiters `[ ,:]` and special chars, which are part of the word: `[\$\[\]\@\%]`. It should be something like this:

```
((\w*[\$\[\]\@\%]+\w*)+?)[ ,:]*
```

If you can, add a space to the end of the source string, so you can use mandatory delimiters without loosing last word:

```
((\w*[\$\[\]\@\%]+\w*)+?)[ ,:]+
```